# Maintaining a single collection subdivided by a value's property

Tags: c#

I'm working on a networked game. In this game, the base entity is called an actor. An actor can either be replicated or local, with each instance having a "replicates" field that represents this.

When managing a scene, a collection of actor must be maintained. My problem is finding a suitable solution to this. Right now I store a collection of references to local actors, replicated actors and all actors. This means data is duplicated which results in code like this:

```
        for( int i = 0; i < actorsToRemove.Count; ++i )
        {
            if( actorsToRemove[i].Replicates )
            {
                replicatedActors.Remove( actorsToRemove[i].Id );
            }
            else
            {
                localActors.Remove( actorsToRemove[i] );
            }
            allActors.Remove( actorsToRemove[i] );
        }
        actorsToRemove.Clear();
```

Instead of just removing from a single collection.

I could have one single collection that holds all actors and use properties that return another collection. For example:

```
public List<Actor> ReplicatedActors
{
    get
    {
        // loop through all actors and return a new list that holds all replicating actors.
    }
}
```

But this seems like too much unnecessary copying.

What would be the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you suggested is absolutely fine. There isn't any unnecessary copying. Although, to make things simpler, I suggest using LINQ extension methods for filtering.

```
using System.Linq;

public IEnumerable<Actor> ReplicatedActors
{
    get { return allActors.Where(actor => actor.Replicates); }
}

public IEnumerable<Actor> LocalActors
{
    get { return allActors.Where(actor => !actor.Replicates); }
}
```

You'll still have to remove actors from `allActors`, these two are separate read-only lists of actors derived from the list of all actors.

Edit: I also suggest changing your actor removal loop to be a `foreach` loop for simplicity.

```
foreach (var actor in actorsToRemove)
{
    allActors.Remove(actor);
}
actorsToRemove.Clear();
```

Comment: But those properties return an entirely new list with all the references copied over, right? Do you think the copying is negligible?

Comment: Yes, they are entirely new lists. Both properties use `IEnumerable` as return types, so they're lazily evaluated. The copying doesn't matter unless `allActors` is massive in size. Microsoft's implementation of the CLR has a maximum of 2GB for object sizes. For most lists, that means hundreds of millions of items, if not billions. If you run into problems with the list size, you should look into ways of reducing it or caching `ReplicatedActors` and `LocalActors`.

Comment: Do you suggest LINQ for any reason other than it's conciseness?

Comment: It's powerful, it's simple, it's lazy, and these are just the extension methods. Actual LINQ is all those and even more. [Here's a great resource on getting started with LINQ.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

If you have three lists (localActors, replicatedActors, allActors) and you want to remove from them elements from actorsToRemove (with corresponding flag), you can utilise `.Except` method:

```
localActors = localActors.Except(actorsToRemove.Where(a => !a.Replicates).ToList();
replicatedActors = replicatedActors.Except(actorsToRemove.Where(a => a.Replicates).ToList();
allActors = allActors.Except(actorsToRemove).ToList();
actorsToRemove.Clear();
```

The solution with properties doesn't do exactly that. Using properties has the advantage that you can avoid storing data in three separate collections. It'll require using those properties inside a single class, and will not work for random lists.

Edit: My original idea with `.RemoveRange` was totally wrong, sorry. `.Except` should work with any `IEnumerable<>` though. It looks a bit noisy to my liking though :(.